# Custom annotation binding in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Let's say I have the following method in my `Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = "")
@ResponseBody
public Object getObject(@MyAnnotation String value) {
   log.debug(value) //value is populated
   ...
}
```

How would I go about binding something from the request to this annotated value? Does Spring offer any hooks into the binding process? Would be great if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Spring uses the [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) (you can see the default ones in the `All Known Implementing Classes` area of the javadoc) interface to decide what to pass into your controller method.

You can create and register your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to find your annotation.

```
public class MyHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null;
    }

    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                           ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                           NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                           WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        // do something about it
    }
}
```

Spring iterates through a `List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>` of registered resolvers (some default, some custom registered), calling `supportsParameter()`. It uses the first one it finds that supports the parameter in question.

To register with programmatic configuration, you can extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and override its method

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherContext extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new MyHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

On a side note, you can do the same thing for handler method return values with `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`.

Comment: You're the man -- was looking at HandlerMethodArgumentResolver on github, but your answer clears it all up.

Comment: You can also use `hasParameterAnnotation` instead of `getParameterAnnotation`

Comment: Is there a way to get hold of the value of the parameter in `resolveArgument`?